# Robust Linear Model - No exogenous var, just constants

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm doing a robust linear regression on only a constant (a column of 1s) and no exogenous variable. I'm able to calculate the model just fine by inputting a list of 1's equal to the size of the 'xi_list' from the code snippet below.

```
def sigma_and_miu(gvkey, statevar_dict):

statevar_list = statevar_dict[gvkey]

xi_list = [np.log(statevar_list[i]) - np.log(statevar_list[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(statevar_list))]

x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array(xi_list)

rlm_model = sm.RLM(y, x, M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT())
rlm_results = rlm_model.fit()

sigma = np.std(rlm_results.resid * rlm_results.weights)

miudelta = rlm_results.params[0] + (0.5 * sigma ** 2)

return miudelta, sigma
```

This function is ran with the following inputs.

```
dict = {1004:[1796.6, 1938.6, 2085.4, 2009.4, 1906.1, 2002.2, 2164.9, 2478.8, 2357.4, 2662.1, 2911.2, 2400.4, 2535.9, 2812.3, 2873.1, 2775.5, 3374.2, 3345.5, 3466.3, 2409.4]}
key = 1004
miu, sigma = sigma_and_miu(key,dict)
```

However, I'm looking for a more scalable approach. I was thinking that one solution could be to include a loop that appends as many 1's as the length of the xi_list variable but, this does not seem to be very efficient.

I know there is sm.add_constant() and I tried to add this constant to my 'y' variable and leaving 'x' blank in the sm.RLM() function. This results in not being able to run the model.

So my question is, whether there is a better way to create the list of 1s or should I just go for the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use basic numpy vectorized computation

e.g.

```
statevar = np.asarray(statevar_list)
y = np.log(statevar[1:]) - np.log(statevar[:-1])
x = np.ones(len(y))
```

Aside: The `rlm_results` should have the robust estimate of the standard deviation that is used in the estimation as a scale attribute.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the np.ones() function. Could you elaborate on the robust estimate of the stdev part? I searched here but couldn't find anything: http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.RLMResults.html#statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.RLMResults

Comment: see the description of `scale` in the attribute list on that page. The estimation method for scale is chosen by `scale_est` option in fit http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.RLM.fit.html